# How to save a website copy into different folders each time using wget?

Tags: pipe, wget

I have this going in cron:

```
0 0 1 * * wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent http://example.com -P /foo/bar
```

I'd like save the wget output in a folder (e.g. /foo/bar-2022-04-27/) with the date of download so I have snapshots of the website each month. I'm thinking it needs to be piped to something, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` will create the path if it does not exist, so instead of:

```
-P /foo/bar
```

you can use:

```
-P /foo/$(date --rfc-3339=date)
```

and that will save files to, for example,  `foo/2022-04-07`. You can format the date to fit your needs.

Comment: I couldn't have had a more beautiful answer, thanks!